# unrecognized command line option '-march' when I try to make install yuvmotionfps

Tags: linux, makefile

When I try to install yuvmotionfps-1.6 (http://jcornet.free.fr/linux/yuvmotionfps.html).
I run into the following error when running make, it seems like (gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-march') is the problem.

How do I fix this?

Here is the output of my install process (I truncated some of the seemingly unnecessary output):

**`sudo ./configure`**

```
.....................
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating yuvmotionfps/Makefile
config.status: creating utils/Makefile
config.status: creating utils/altivec/Makefile
config.status: creating utils/mmxsse/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing mjpegtools-config.h commands
config.status: creating mjpegtools-config.h (prefix MJPEGTOOLS for config.h)
config.status: mjpegtools-config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: 
configure:  MJPEG tools 1.7.0 build configuration :
configure: 
configure:   - X86 Optimizations:
configure:     - MMX/3DNow!/SSE enabled      : true
configure:   - arch/cpu compiler flags       : Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'.
configure:   - video4linux recording/playback: true
configure:   - software MJPEG playback       : true
configure:   - MPEG Z/Alpha                  : false
configure:   - Quicktime playback/recording  : false
configure:   - PNG input support             : true
configure:   - AVI MJPEG playback/recording  : true (always)
configure:   - libDV (digital video) support : false 
configure:   - Gtk+ support for glav         : true
configure:
```

**`sudo sh autogen.sh`**

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
utils/Makefile.am:14: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
utils/altivec/Makefile.am:3: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
utils/mmxsse/Makefile.am:3: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
yuvmotionfps/Makefile.am:5: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
```

**`sudo make`**

```
................
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6'
Making all in utils
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils'
Making all in mmxsse
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils/mmxsse'
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../utils    Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'. -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wunused -MT build_sub22_mests.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/build_sub22_mests.Tpo -c -o build_sub22_mests.lo build_sub22_mests.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../utils Your does not even support i386 for -march and -mcpu. -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wunused -MT build_sub22_mests.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/build_sub22_mests.Tpo -c build_sub22_mests.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/build_sub22_mests.o
gcc: error: Your: No such file or directory
gcc: error: does: No such file or directory
gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
gcc: error: even: No such file or directory
gcc: error: support: No such file or directory
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: for: No such file or directory
gcc: error: and: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-march'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mcpu.'
make[3]: *** [build_sub22_mests.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils/mmxsse'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**`sudo make install`**

```
Making install in utils
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils'
Making install in mmxsse
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils/mmxsse'
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../utils    Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'. -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wunused -MT build_sub22_mests.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/build_sub22_mests.Tpo -c -o build_sub22_mests.lo build_sub22_mests.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../utils Your does not even support i386 for -march and -mcpu. -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wunused -MT build_sub22_mests.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/build_sub22_mests.Tpo -c build_sub22_mests.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/build_sub22_mests.o
gcc: error: Your: No such file or directory
gcc: error: does: No such file or directory
gcc: error: not: No such file or directory
gcc: error: even: No such file or directory
gcc: error: support: No such file or directory
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: for: No such file or directory
gcc: error: and: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-march'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mcpu.'
make[2]: *** [build_sub22_mests.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils/mmxsse'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/simon/Applications/yuvmotionfps-1.6/utils'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like for some reason the following error message crept in the makefiles when autogen.sh was run:

`CFLAGS='Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'. -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Wunused'`

I removed the sentence `'Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'.` from all the makefiles. That lead to a successful compilation.